# Why does it typecheck and how?

Tags: haskell

I am reading the paper *Applcative programming with effects* from Conor McBride and Ross Paterson and I can't figure out why their first piece of code typechecks. (I have a strong OCaml background and a weak haskell background).

There is a function `ap` from `Control.Monad` with the following type:

```
ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

This function can easily be written like this:

```
ap mf mx = do { f <- mf ; x <- mx ; return (f x) }
```

Then they write the following:

```
sequence :: [IO a] → IO [a]
sequence [] = return []
sequence (c : cs) = return (:) `ap` c `ap` sequence cs
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to work out the type of `` (:) `ap` c `ap` sequence cs `` by hand because the type of `(:)` is nowhere close to `m (a -> b)` since it is `a -> ([a] -> [a])`.

The type of `ap (Just (:))` is `Maybe a -> (Maybe ([a] -> [a]))` just as expected but the typechecker tells me that the type of `ap (:)` is `(a -> [a]) -> a -> [a]`. How is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are writing

```
return (:) `ap` c `ap` sequence cs
```

Then, with explicit parenthesization, it's

```
((return (:)) `ap` c) `ap` (sequence cs)
```

So,

```
(:)                           :: a -> [a] -> [a]
return (:)                    :: IO (a -> [a] -> [a])
c                             :: IO a
(return (:)) `ap` c           :: IO ([a] -> [a])
sequence cs                   :: IO [a]
((return (:)) `ap` c) `ap` cs :: IO [a]
```

For your second question, `ap (:)` is using the Monad instance for `(->) a`, where

```
-- Monad instance for ((->) a)
return x = \_ -> x
x >>= f  = \y -> f (x y) y
```

so, you have:

```
ap :: (a -> (b -> c)) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
ap f g = \x -> f x (g x)
```

If you just looked at the do-block definition of `ap` and expanded out the definitions.

Chances are that this second question probably isn't going to be too important or critical for now; focus on the answer to the first one for now :)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and pointing out the Monad instance of `(->) a` it removes the magic.